# Grabbing data from steamapi (json) and importing it to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I can't quite figure out how to import data from remote json (steamapi) into MySql.

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
mysql_select_db('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',$con);

$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=76561198033811393";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($json);
foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
    if($value)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO steam (steamid, 
                                        communityvisibilitystate, 
                                        profilestate) 
                                VALUES ($value->steamid,
                                        $value->communityvisibilitystate,
                                        $value->profilestate)");
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Steam JSON Image(click for full size):
[image: Click to resize]

Comment: `var_dump($result->response->players);` or `var_dump($result->players);`

Comment: `var_dump($result);` & check your result object format.

Comment: Please put echo "<pre>"; and print_r($result) and Show your responce

Comment: I think image is showing the `var_dump($result)`. he is closing the connection of `mysql` in first iteration. that may be the issue. he can also use `json_decode($result,true)` this will give `key` `val` pair array.

Comment: @prix http://s23.postimg.org/3xxfp5evt/Untitled.png <--- Var Dump

Comment: @NathanSrivi http://s12.postimg.org/rm2d6us23/Untitled.png is the one you requested

Comment: @user3150487 use `json_decode($result,true)` this will give `key` `val` pair `array`. and close the connection of mysql after loop is over.

Comment: @prix yeah that was the first one

Comment: @user3150487 do you check my answer

Comment: @NathanSrivi since you just edited let me try again

Comment: @NathanSrivi http://s30.postimg.org/5jgtton8f/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read each player using `$data->response->players`, it will be assigned to `$player` where then, you can directly access their object like `$player->steamid`. See below example:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->response->players as $player)
{
    echo $player->steamid, "\n\n";
}
```

I also suggest you change your query like this:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO steam (steamid,
                                     communityvisibilitystate,
                                     profilestate) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')",
                mysql_real_escape_string($player->steamid),
                mysql_real_escape_string($player->communityvisibilitystate),
                mysql_real_escape_string($player->profilestate));
```

To prevent any further issues like broken strings or injections.

Resulting code for the SQL part would be:

```
// Build the query
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO steam (steamid,
                                     communityvisibilitystate,
                                     profilestate) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')",
                mysql_real_escape_string($player->steamid),
                mysql_real_escape_string($player->communityvisibilitystate),
                mysql_real_escape_string($player->profilestate));

// Perform Query
$insert = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$insert)
{
    echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    echo 'Whole query: ' . $query . "\n";
    echo "------------------\n";
}
```

Given your actual code it would look like this:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
mysql_select_db('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',$con);

$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=76561198033811393";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->response->players as $player)
{
    // Build the query
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO steam (steamid,
                                         communityvisibilitystate,
                                         profilestate) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($player->steamid),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($player->communityvisibilitystate),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($player->profilestate));

    // Perform Query
    $insert = mysql_query($query);

    // Check result
    // This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
    if (!$insert)
    {
        echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        echo 'Whole query: ' . $query . "\n";
        echo "------------------\n";
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: This worked thank you! P.S. I will be using PDO in my production website.

Comment: @user3150487 as you were using it right now you query would break if it had spaces doesn't even need to be a injection so that could also be one of the reasons it was giving you a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    <?php
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $key = 'xxx';

        $link = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' . $key . '&steamids=76561198033811393&format=json');
        $myarray = json_decode($link, true);

        $result =  $myarray['response']['players'][0];
        echo $result->steamid;
    ?>
```

if you get more then one result use `foreach` format given below

```
 $result = $myarray['response']['players'];
    foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {
    echo $value->steamid."<br>";
}
```